# Threejs mesh matrix getInverse Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

Tags: three.js

I have baisc problem that I am strugling to solve using the ThreeJs apis, due to an exception of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

Essentially this is very basic problem that most likely boils to some improper use of the threejs apis (perhaps i have the wrong assumption / understanding of what a mesh.matrix represents).

The problem I am trying to solve is utterly basic.

I have some offset coordinates (x,y,z) where the (x,y,z) is a vluae 
 in the world coordinate system. 
Let us call this x,y,z offset coordinates the concept of  "Approach".

And this approach represents some offset distance away from an abitrary object that we can call "SomeObject".

The ultimate goal is that it would be nice to represent this distance away as sphere in the air that would be added to the scene as child object of SomeObject.

Obvisouly, I cannot simply take these (x,y,z) representing an offset in real world coordinates and simply add my sphere as:

```
Approach.x = x;
Approach.y = y;
Approach.z = z;
SomeObject.add(appraoch)
```

This pseudo code above is completely wrong.
This code above makes no sense, it would only work when the SomeObject orientation to the world is 0 degrees.  On all other situations the X,Y,Z axis of SomeObject will not coincice with the positions of the world coordinate system and the Sphere would appear on the wrong side of my object.
In short, this Offset must be translated from world coordinates into SomeObject coordinates.

Mathematically, what I am saying is trivial.
The problem to be solved is nothing more that the following Homogeneous Transformation Matrix multiplication.

```
meshApproachTo2SomecObject = wolrd2SomeObjectMatrix X meshApproach2World.matrix;
```

That is all and game over.

The code I tried to run looks as follows:

```
var whitekMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xFFFFF} );
var dummyGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 50);

var meshApproach2World = new THREE.Mesh( dummyGeometry, whitekMaterial );
meshApproach2World.position.x = 560;
meshApproach2World.position.y = -760;
meshApproach2World.position.z = 381;
meshApproach2World.updateMatrix();
// meshApproach2World.matrix.getPosition()


var someOject2World = new THREE.Mesh( dummyGeometry, whitekMaterial );
someOject2World.position.x = 0;
someOject2World.position.y = 0;
someOject2World.position.z = 0;
someOject2World.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
someOject2World.updateMatrix();


// compute the COORDINATES of the APPRORACH OBJECT Relative to the "SOmeObject
// Mathmathicall APPROACH2SomeObject= World2SomeObject X Apporache2World
// Therefore
var wolrd2SomeObjectMatrix = someOject2World.matrix.getInverse();


// Do later 
// ApproachOffset2SomecObjectMatrix = wolrd2SomeObjectMatrix X ApproachOffset2WorldMatrix;
```

Obviously if in the exercise above my SomeObject is 90 degrees rotated relative to the world coordinate system, the transformation of (x,y,z) = (560, -760, 381)
is supposed to return:

> coordinates=CalcCoordinates [x=-760.0, y=-560.0, z=381.0] ,
>   orientation=CalcOrientation [aYawDegrees=270.0, bPitchDegrees=-0.0,
>   cRollDegrees=0.0]

x2=Y1
Y2=-X1
Z2=Z1

However, I get stuck when I try to get the coordinates of the world relative to my some object.

When I try to get the inverse matrix:

```
var wolrd2SomeObjectMatrix = someOject2World.matrix.getInverse();
```

Threejs blows up.

I thought that when you have a mesh in threejs, the MATRIX represents HTM from that object relative to the world.

you should threfore be able to get the mesh 4x4 matrix and ask for its inverse.
Instead it blows up... with this not so understandable exception.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, you can directly set the `(x,y,z)` position of the child object in world coordinates. So long as you utilize the method [.attach()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.attach) on its parent. Instead of the usual `add()`. `parent.attach(child)`

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's a [Object3D.worldToLocal()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.worldToLocal) method you can utilize to transform a vector from world coordinates to the object's local coordinates. `parent.worldToLocal( child.position )`

Comment: Brilliant. To the coordinate transformation I just need to be careful to update the world matrix (since my dummy objects are not being added to the scene just being created to facilitate the data transformation).  someOject2World.updateMatrixWorld();  someOject2World.worldToLocal(meshApproach2World.position); is exactly what I wanted.